# Tiling $41$ unit squares with $L$ tetrominoes and $L$ trominoes

Tags: combinatorics, tiling

In the given figure, there are $41$ unit squares. We want tile to the figure with $L$-tetrominoes and $L$-trominoes. Determine all possible numbers of usable $L$-tetrominoes? Please, prove your answer wiht supporter figures.

[image]

**Notes:**

1. We can rotate and reflect some of $L$-tetrominoes and $L$-trominoes for the tiling operations. Also, number of $L$-tetrominoes and number of $L$-trominoes can be different.
2. Problem is mine and I have its solution. I have sent for sharing. I hope that you like it.

Comment: Have you thought about how many ways there are to add up $3$s and $4$s to make $41$?  I strongly suspect all of those are possible, so would just try to find a solution.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: It's own writing problem and I sent it for sharing. (I didn't stuck).

Comment: Are you saying the number of tetrominoes is equal to the number of trominoes (both equal to $L$)?  That would be impossible because 41 is not a multiple of 7.

Comment: No, I didn't say anywhere that number of tetrominoes is equal to the number of trominoes. They must be different.

Comment: If you are not stuck then perhaps you should clarify what your Question is about.  Have you found some numbers $m$ of $L$-tetrominoes that work?  Perhaps you intend the Question not to help you learn (e.g. about the techniques for solving such tiling problems) but rather as a challenge to Readers.  The Question may be off-topic if offered in that spirit here, but look at some previous posts at Puzzling.SE for comparison.

Comment: `Prove your answer` Seems to be rude and looks like you are ordering us.

Comment: Sorry @Jaideep Khare , English is not my native language. I don't know some of niceness of English language. In my native language, means of ''Prove your answer'' more or less ''May you prove your answer, please?''. That is, ''numbers of $L$ tetrominos are $2,5,8$'' is an answer but not copmlete solution. If you can give some examples about tiling figures, then your solutions will be complete.

Comment: Thanks for your interest @hardmath . I belive that my problem very clarify. I didn't understand why can be off-topic? There are many times similar problems in math.stackexchange.com. Also, Ross Millikan gave the main line of the solution in his comment. Furthermore, the problem completly solved by Misha Lavrov, yesterday and I gave accepting vote for his nice solution. I wrotre a problem in here about basic of tilling for loving this type (tilling problems) solvers. I hope that I sent a useful problem and there is no mistake the problem. Please and please you don't give off-topic for prblm.

Comment: You should edit your post to explicitly state that the numbers of the tetrominoes and trominoes could be different, and that $L$ here is a descriptor (and not a variable representing the number of polyominoes). You could rewrite it as "L-tetrominoes" and "L-trominoes" (with a dash).

Comment: I edited my post and I wrote $L$-tetromino, $L$-tromino ...etc. But already, there is no any intimating state in the sentence of problem about equality (or inequality) numbers of the pieces. In some problems, numbers of some pieces may be equal. In some kind of problems, numbers of some pieces could be different.In both case, we don't say anything about equality and we expect that solvers find something with a rigorous and detailed solution. Otherwise, more informations will be a hint.Finally, to your glading, I will write to the problem 'the numbers of  tetrominoes and ... could be different'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are $p$ trominoes and $q$ tetrominoes, then $3p + 4q = 41$, which has $3$ solutions over the positive integers: $(p,q) \in \{(3,8), (7,5), (11, 2)\}$. Each of these is possible, as shown below:

[image: tilings]

Both in the tilings and in the positive integer equations, the idea is that we can replace three tetrominoes by four trominoes while still covering the same total area.

Comment: Nice explantion! +1

Comment: beautiful diagrams!  really above and beyond, bravo.